# Change current url in html4

Tags: url, html4

Is there any way to change current URL that is shown in address bar using JavaScript or jQuery and HTML 4 without redirecting?

An example could be like this:

Current URL: `www.mypage.com?Id=12&AnotherId=98`

And I like to be modified after page has been loaded like `www.mypage.com`

Is that possible?

Comment: No. HTML is not a functional language. It is descriptive, it describes the documents mark up. Maybe you'll think javascript, I'm not 100% certain, but I think not, for security purposes. Think allong the lines off chaning,on the browser, www.myphisingwebsite.com to www.mytrstedbank.com. You can do URL rewritting on the serverside to produce pretty urls like you mention using PHP/JPS/ASP.net etc.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in modern browsers using JavaScript, like that:

```
 window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/myPage');
```

This changes URL to `www.mypage.com/myPage`

In older "HTML4" browsers you can only change part of the URL that comes after `#`.

```
 parent.location.hash='myPage'
```

This changes URL to `www.mypage.com#myPage`

If you want older browsers graceful support, checkout [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js). In older browsers it works by changing hash part of the URL, but in modern browsers the whole URL is changed.

Note that ability to change full page URL using JavaScript does not depend on what Doctype is used, HTML5, or not, it only depends on browser capabilities.